# Drop down select box with php

Tags: php, select, combobox

I wrote some php to deliver a select box. For some reason it refuses to select the correct option. When I try the HTML directly it works. To check I wasn't doing anything stupid. I copied the generated code and they put the code to generate and the html.

```
<dd>
  <select id="jform_my_foreign_key" class="inputbox " name="jform[my_foreign_key]" size="1">
   <option value="">- Select Order title -</option>
   <option value="13">00000013</option>
   <option value="12">00000012</option>
   <option value="9" selected="selected">00000009</option>
   <option value="8">00000008</option>
   <option value="7">00000001</option>
</select>
  </dd>

<select id="jform_my_foreign_key" class="inputbox " size="1" name="jform[my_foreign_key]">
   <option value="">- Select Order title -</option>
   <option value="13">00000013</option>
   <option value="12">00000012</option>
   <option selected="selected" value="9">00000009</option>
   <option value="8">00000008</option>
   <option value="7">00000001</option>
</select>
```

The top is generated by the php code and the bottom is me putting the html directly into 
the page

Code used is:

```
<dd><select id="jform_my_foreign_key" class="inputbox " size="1" name="jform[my_foreign_key]">
  <option value="">- Select Order title -</option>

<?php
                for($x=0;$x<count($ordersAvailableHoldingArray);$x+=2){
  if($ordersUseHoldingArray[0] ==$ordersAvailableHoldingArray[$x+1]){
$selected ="selected='selected'";
  }else{
$selected ="";
}
echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$ordersAvailableHoldingArray[$x].'">'.$ordersAvailableHoldingArray[$x+1].'</option>';
}
?>

  </select></dd>
```

I can't figure out why it doesn't work it looks right to me. Any help where to start debugging would be great

Comment: Could you add a `var_dump($ordersAvailableHoldingArray)` to the question, please?

Comment: In `for($x=0;$x<count($ordersAvailableHoldingArray);$x+=2){` - shouldn't `$x+=1`? It's making a **jump** from **0 to 2**, *just saying*.

Comment: What is the problem? Both HTML snippets are essentially equivalent and they both work fine for me. Am I missing the obvious?

Comment: I think I'm also missing **the "obvious"**. `@OP`, post the code that actually **does the work**. *I never did show up in Mind-Reading classes*.

Comment: Does this by any chance have anything to do with **Joomla**? I ask this, because all your other questions are Joomla-based.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using a **foreach** to put key and value in select as example below.

```
<form action="" method="post">

<select id="jform_my_foreign_key" class="inputbox" name="jform[my_foreign_key]"  size="1">
<option value="">- Select Order title -</option>
            <?php 

            $data_for_select = array(13=>'00000013',12=>'00000012',9=>'0000009');

            foreach($data_for_select as $k=>$v)
            { 
            if($k==$_POST['jform']['my_foreign_key'])
            {
                echo "<option value=\"$k\" selected=\"selected\">$v</option>";
                }
            else
            {
                echo "<option value=\"$k\">$v</option>";
                } 
            } 
            ?>
            </select>

<input name="jello" type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

Comment: I'm sure the OP is well aware of that. If you would go over the question again carefully, you will see that his HTML is **"dynamically generated"**. So your answer is **invalid**. FYI: If you get `downvoted`, it won't be from me, I'm not like that. Yet I would re-think your answer. Cheers

Comment: thanks.what are `$ordersUseHoldingArray[0]` `$ordersAvailableHoldingArray[$x+1]` as these hold the key to answer. whats store in them and how as i thought `$_POST['jform']['my_foreign_key']==$ordersUseHoldingArray[0]` or `$_POST['jform']['my_foreign_key']==$ordersUseHoldingArray[0]`

Comment: I don't know to be honest with you. I don't know where the OP got his code from. But I'm sure he's not showing us his entire source.

Comment: Personally, I think this question (The OP's) is **dead in the water**. *Giving up*.